# Project Euler #8 code implementation

Tags: java, programming-challenge

> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product." eg, the product of the first four adjacent
>   digits is 7 * 3 * 1 * 6 = 126

```
public class Java {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    long max = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < temp.length()-12 ; i++){
        int min = temp.charAt(i)-48;
        long product = 1;
        for(int k = i ; k < 13+i ; k++){
            min =  Math.min(temp.charAt(k) - 48 , min);
            if( min == 0)
                {product = 0;
                break;}
            else {
                product = product*(temp.charAt(k)-48);
            }
        }

             if(product > max){
                 max = product;
             }




    }
     System.out.println("max : " + max);

    }
}
```

The code works perfectly and runtime is around 925323ns.

I had realized after posting
 that finding the minimum was useless... so forgive me for that....

Comment: i think it was pretty stupid of me to find minimum and then check for the minimum to be zero.... I could have simply checked for the zero directly...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing you should do is clean your code up.

We should notice that `temp.charAt(k)-48` is called no less than once, and no more than twice in the `for (int k...)` loop. We can fix that (quite easily).

Next, we should notice that if we find a `0` in our second loop, we can skip that many numbers ahead.

Lastly, `aChar - 48` is bad practice. In Java you can subtract *single-character literals*. Instead of `aChar - 48`, let's do `aChar - '0'`. The 48 becomes a magic number, and it's just as easy to subtract the `'0'` instead. :)

```
public class Java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        long max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length() - 12; i++) {
            int min = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
            long product = 1;

            for (int k = i; k < 13 + i; k++) {
                int numK = temp.charAt(k) - '0';
                min =  Math.min(numK, min);

                if (min == 0) {
                    product = 0;
                    i = k + 1; // The value at `k` is a zero, so we'll not bother processing from `i through k`.
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    product = product * numK;
                }
            }

            if (product > max) {
                max = product;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("max : " + max);
    }
}
```

---

Or, of course, rewrite the entire thing to one loop instead, which would be the preferred method.

```
public class Java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        long max = 0;
        long runningProduct = 1;
        int numbersLoaded = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            int numI = temp.charAt(i) - '0';

            if (numI == 0) {
                runningProduct = 1;
                numbersLoaded = 0;
            }
            else {
                if (numbersLoaded == 13) {
                    runningProduct /= temp.charAt(i - 13) - '0';
                }
                else {
                    numbersLoaded += 1;
                }

                runningProduct *= numI;

                if (runningProduct > max) {
                    max = runningProduct;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("max : " + max);
    }
}
```

I will warn you, if taken out of context the following line **is** dangerous:

```
runningProduct /= temp.charAt(i - 13) - '0';
```

This could *definitely* cause a division by 0 error if not handled properly. (It's handled properly here, but could easily be made not to be.)

Here's a link to [ideone](https://ideone.com/APMiu2) with the two tests, for comparison.

All-in-all, I hope this was helpful. :)

Comment: the idea of skipping that many numbers ahead was good..... and you really solved the '0' problem....

Comment: @AltamashKhan Not a problem, you can also see it in action [here](https://ideone.com/APMiu2).

Comment: Great implementation..... loved your code.

Comment: This is kind of a pedantic remark, but the OP's implementation is not \$O(n^2)\$, but \$O(13 n)\$, which is actually \$O(n)\$. Nice code, anyway!

Comment: @Jaime I had a suspicion about that, I had asked someone to check on it but no one did. :(

Comment: One last thing I would add, `aChar - 48` is poor style, 48 is a magic number.  `aChar - '0'` makes it much clearer what you're doing.

Comment: @MattPutnam I knew you could do that in C#, was unaware it was valid in Java. :)

Comment: @MattPutnam Updated.

Comment: I implemented your idea... http://pastebin.com/V6dtmZhr  time took about 
277761 ns.... yours took about 302591 ns.....    thanks a ton for all the help..... this was my first post in stackexchange..... and i m overwhelmed by all the help i got from all you guys.... :)

Answer (score 7):

Let's examine the first five adjecent digits, they are

```
7 * 3 * 1 * 6 * 7 = 882
```

and if you now compare it to the second five adjecent digits:

```
3 * 1 * 6 * 7 * 1 = 126
```

From that we can easily see that we can get the solution for the second equation if we devide the solution of the first equation by the first number(7) and multiply that with the next number (in this case 1).

Same logic can be applied to the 13 digit product.

What I'm saying is... you don't need nested loops.

**EDIT:**
sorry... forgot about the "zero problem"

I just thought of something...
why not replace all ocurences of 0 with -1, would that help?
I didn't think this one throuhg, but this is basicaly what I had in mind:
0 is problematic only when we try to devide with it.

Let's see on an example:
let's say we have the input:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

then

0 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 0

if we replace the 0 with -1 we get

```
-1 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = -24
```

the product of the next five digits is:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120
```

which is equal (-24 / -1) * 5

as we can see... division with -1 is not problematic

Comment: Yes.. i understand.. but then i had the problem with the zeroes.....  so i got messed up....

Comment: @AltamashKhan oh... I see... I didn't think of that

Comment: While this is good advice generally, indeed there is a problem with zeros that has to be figured out. This is a step in the right direction though, now solve the zero problem :)

Comment: can't we shorten the code by doing something with the 0's and the 1's .... i  am just not good enough to come with a suitable algo... :/

Comment: that would be problematic.....  i guess.... i will have a negative number .... can you explain in a bit detail..... how would -1 help?

Comment: yea... but the product of the first five digits became -24 instead of 0 and if i try to only turn the 0 to -1 if i see it in the first place.... then i  will have to run another loop to check if the digit at first place is 0 or not......  but i will try this method..... this method seems much better and probably one of the best had there been no 0s.... :D thanx

Comment: @AltamashKhan  so what if the product of the firs five digits is -24... you are only interested in finding the maximum, so product that has 0 in it will probably not be the maximum unless there are zeros at every 13th place, in which case you will get negative number as the maximum product(using the forementioned algorithm). But that is the special case that you can handle while outputing the solution, if the max product is less than zero, max product iz zero. Good luck, have fun implementing :)

Comment: aah..... thnx a lot for going all the way to explain it..... pretty neat..... i forgot i just had to output the maximum....  on my way to implement it...  :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not call that string `huge_number`? Temp makes no sense here. The `min` code is confusing and unnecessary, just use `if(temp.charAt(k)-48==0) break;` So your revised code would look something like this:

```
public class Java {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String huge_number = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    long max = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < huge_number.length()-12 ; i++){
        long product = 1;
        for(int k = i ; k < 13+i ; k++){
            if(huge_number.charAt(k-48) == 0){
                product = 0;
                break;
            }
            else {
                product = product*(huge_number.charAt(k)-48);
            }
        }
             if(product > max){
                 max = product;
             }
    }
     System.out.println("max : " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i commented that..... ... i realized that "min" is useless....